# Prove that $I$ and $R/I$ are principal ideal rings if and only if $R$ is a principal ideal ring.

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be an Artinian ring with identity and let $I$ be an ideal of $R$.  Prove that $I$ and $R/I$ are  principal ideal rings if and only if $R$ is a principal ideal ring.

Proof: ($\Leftarrow$) If $R$ is a PIR and artinian, then it is precisely a $0$-dimensional Noetherian ring.  But for any such ring, there is a canonical direct product decomposition $$R\cong \prod R_m$$ where $m$ varies through the finitely many maximal ideals of $R$.  Thus, $R$ being PIR, its Jacobson radical $J(R)$ must be a principal ideal.

($\Rightarrow$) However, I have failed to prove the this side.  What I am sure of is that if $I$ is equal to the radical of $R$, then $R$ is a PIR iff its radical is a PIR.

Comment: Commutative rings? Or do you mean left-and-right principal?

Comment: And apparently rings possibly without identity?

Comment: I refer to an Artinian left and right principal ideal ring

Comment: @rschwieb how can a quotient ring not have an identity? It is defined by an equivalence relation, so all quotient rings must have an additive identity and an additive inverse. But that's just from my understanding. So correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @fordjones the quotient might not have identity if $R$ doesn’t, but that’s not the main reason I ask. The reason I ask is that the poster says $I$ is a principal ideal ring, and I don’t know if they mean that $I$ has to have an identity or not.

Comment: @mariam I’m afraid your edit doesn’t address my question fully. I’m saying: do *all* your principal ideal rings have to have identity? Like $I$ in particular?

Comment: I don't think all principal ideal rings have identities, in this case.   Especially the ideals of $R$.   I don't know whether it is possible to treat them with identities such as the primitive idempotents (Because $R$ is semiperfect).

Comment: @mariam and you’re also talking about noncommutative localization? I have reservations at the conclusions you’ve drawn already.

Comment: The OP has since posted a [special case](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3433913/29335) as a new problem.