# If $I\subseteq R$ and $R/I$ are both commutative Artinian principal ideal rings, then $R$ is a principal ideal ring.

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be an Artinian ring with unity.  Suppose that the ideal $I\subseteq R$ and the corresponding quotient $R/I$ are both commutative Artinian principal ideal rings, show that $R$ is a principal ideal ring.

My attempt:  Suppose that $I=\mathcal{N}(R)$, that is, $I$ coincides with the nil radical, then $R$ is a principal ideal ring since $\mathcal{N}(R)$ is principal ideal ring and $R$ is Artinian.

The remaining case is if $I\subset \mathcal{N}(R)$, then there exist $I\subset J\subset \mathcal{N}(R)$.  This is where I run out of ideas.

Comment: This question still seems to have the same unclarity your [earlier version](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3409671/29335) had.  You really want $I$ to be a (possibly nonunital) principal ideal ring?

Comment: The two questions together suggest you are "fishing" for answers to a question you don't actually know is solvable. That leads me to ask: what's the source?

Comment: I am following the fact that $R$ is Artinian iff both $I$ and $R/I$ are Artinian from the book [Algebras, rings and modules by Hazewinkel, Michiel and Gubareni, Nadiya and Kirichenko, Vladimir V. (Proposition 3.1.3)].   Which implies that this is true for Principal Ideal Rings.

Answer (score 1):

This is false.  For instance, if $R=\mathbb{F}_2[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2)$ and $I=(x)$ then $I$ is a principal ideal rng and $R/I\cong \mathbb{F}_2[y]/(y^2)$ is a principal ideal ring but $R$ is not a principal ideal ring since the ideal $(x,y)$ is not principal.